# Linearity in the conditional for conditional expectation

Tags: probability, linear-transformations, expected-value, conditional-expectation

We know that $E[X+Y|Z] = E[X|Z] + E[Y|Z]$, is it true that $E[X|Y+Z] = E[X|Y] + E[Y|Z]$. If not is there another way to disjoin $E[X|Y+Z]$?

Comment: no it's not true, and no for your last question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditioning on random variables means you condition on their generated sigma algebra, so unless there is a specific structure you are asking to decompose $\sigma(X+Z)$ which could be "many things".

The closest I can come up with is the Bayes theorem for the conditional density (assuming independence) telling you that for any $z$
$$f_{X|X+Z=z}(x)
=\frac{f_{X+Z|X=x}(z)f_X(x)}{f_{X+Y}(z)}
=\frac{f_{x+Z}(z)f_X(x)}{f_{X}*f_{Y}(z)}.
$$
That of course does not disjoin but is the closest to telling you something about the effect of conditioning.